# Saving data to SQLite from JSON Android

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I'd like to save a title, an integer, and an url into SQLite database from a JSON webservice. I'm using a code to do that and it's perfectly working when I'm using another url but now I always got this exceptions for every JSON object I'd like to save:

> E/SQLiteLog: (20) statement aborts at 6: [INSERT INTO categories_table(title,imageurl,azon) VALUES (?,?,?)] datatype mismatchE/SQLiteDatabase: 
>   Error inserting title=TÃ¡nctanÃ¡r imageurl=http://80.99.190.2:8080/mobil/download?id=360 azon=71                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)

CTHandler.java:

```
public class CTHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements CategoriesListener {

private static final int CT_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CT_NAME = "CategoriesDatabase.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "categories_table";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_IMAGEURL = "imageurl";
private static final String KEY_AZON = "azon";

String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_TITLE+" TEXT,"+KEY_IMAGEURL+" TEXT,"+KEY_AZON+" TEXT)";
String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;

public CTHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, CT_NAME, null, CT_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void addCategories(CategoriesItem citem) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, citem.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGEURL,citem.getImageurl());
        values.put(KEY_AZON,citem.getAzon());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("problem",e+"");
    }
}

@Override
public ArrayList<CategoriesItem> getAllCategories() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<CategoriesItem> categoriesList = null;
    try{
        categoriesList = new ArrayList<CategoriesItem>();
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        if(!cursor.isLast())
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                CategoriesItem ci = new CategoriesItem();
                ci.setTitle(cursor.getString(0));
                ci.setImageurl(cursor.getString(1));
                ci.setAzon(cursor.getString(2));
                categoriesList.add(ci);
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
    }
    return categoriesList;
}

@Override
public int getCategoriresCount() {
    int num = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        num = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        return num;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

I have tried to use `BOLB` and `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` for imageurl with no success.

This is one JSON object from the array:

```
"channel":[{"title":"MENYASSZONYI RUHA","imageurl":"http://80.99.190.2:8080/mobil/download?id=350","azon":53},
```

This is what I'd like to save and I'd also like that the URL of the image would be save as `String`. I don't like to use Bitmaps and byte[] I'd just like to save like it's the name of the image. If anybody has idea how to do that please response.

Comment: In the `CTHandler` class, you are making the azon to be `Text` type but passing integer while inserting. Please make sure you are passing `String` to that field.

Comment: Should I use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` for azon? I have saved azon as a String and when I'm using `citem.getAzon()` it returns with a String.

Comment: While adding, what you are using for Azon in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 20 means you have not updated the database version after making some changes in database.Uninstall your app and then run again or update your database version code or try changing database name after uninstalling the app..

Comment: Thank you for writing me but unfortunately it's not working, I got the same error. Have you any other idea?

Comment: error code 20 comes with database existence problem as far as i have seen. change the name of the database name or uninstall the app and try again.. This might solve your problrm.

Comment: Thank you, to rename the database and unistall the app solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To save an image, you need to use BLOB datatype. But i have no idea on saving the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this and let me know its worked or not .

Try to save every thing to your DB after doing .toString();

if its not worked you can try below suggestion.

Change this in your code and

```
String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
```

replace with this

```
 String DROP_TABLE = db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

if nothing works try to change the db name once and give a try !

Hope it will help .if its not worked let me know.

Comment: Thank you for writing me but unfortunately non of them works. Have you any other idea?